# React native Application Opens with Blank white Screen

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

My React native application shows blank white screen before the Splash Screen
Please any one help me for solve this error..
You can check my App video here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-1eocUqfJ4_bD-G8zeJobbwb-xbIvOsT/view?usp=sharing

I am using own customized splash screen with react navigation. My app getting some time for opening the app and display blank white screen before splash screen.

While running blank screen then terminal shows only index.bundle and after some time My app SplashScreen componentDidmount() method called.

index.js

```
import {AppRegistry, LogBox} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

if (Platform.OS === 'web') {
const rootTag = document.getElementById('root') || document.getElementById('main');
AppRegistry.runApplication('NameHippo', { rootTag });
}
LogBox.ignoreAllLogs(true)
```

App.js

```
function App() {
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Splash Screen"
        headerMode="none"
        screenOptions={{gestureEnabled: true,}}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Intro Screen" component={IntroScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Main Screen" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Splash Screen" component={SplashScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
);
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Based on the code posted, I can't draw any conclusions... How is the looking of the App component?

Comment: I just added app.js file